# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.subscriptions.SerialSubscription in android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-java, rx-android

FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.subscriptions.SerialSubscription

at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.call(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:87)
                                                                         at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.call(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:45)
                                                                         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:46)
                                                                         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                                                                         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8759)
                                                                         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8726)

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions. Be specific and describe your problem. The stack trace of the error is only one part. Provide relevant code and screenshots if necessary. Otherwise the community cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0' dependency in your build.gradle file of app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have added it as below

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.7'
```

and even the same error it occurs in 4.1 to 4.3

Comment: Is your issue resolved or still having some problem.

Comment: Still the issue persists

Comment: I am not getting this issue on my side. Can you please clean your project then build it again may be dependency not compiled.

Comment: `Could not find class 'rx.subscriptions.SerialSubscription', referenced from method rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.call` is the error Thrown before the error occurs